# Why sqlliteconnection assigned to static variables are disposed?

Tags: c#, sqlite, static-members

I am assigning sqlliteconnection object to static variable and initializing it in a function.

while accessing sqlliteconnection object at some cases it throws "sqlconnection object is disposed" exception. Up to my knowledge static variables are disposed only while application closes.

Sample Code:

```
public static SQLLiteConnection sql;

public void OpenConnection()
{
     sql = new SQLLiteConnection ;
     //assign sql lite file path
     sql.Open();
}

public void GetStud()
{
  OpenConnection();
 //writing sqlcommand connection
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Dispose() even on static object. It's purpose is to release unmanaged resources (managed resources are released automatically by GC). Dispose is not called only after application is closed. It's called automatically typically from finalizer method (called by GC) whenever there is no reference to this object. It's also called on the end of the **using** block.

Anyway, static SqlConnection object is not a good idea. Better always create new instance with "using".

```
using (var conn = new SQLLiteConnection("connectionstring"))
{
   conn.Open();
}//here is called Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable response. May i know the reason why static 
DB connection is not best idea and as for as i know GC clears only unused objects. But i am initializing sqlconnection each and every time it is used then how can GC consider it as unused object. Ya i know it is good to use using keyword. But i can't change entire application as of now.

Comment: When it's static things will become very complicated if you access it by more threads. Also the underlying connections have some overhead. And when some other non-static object like data reader has reference to this static field GC might not collect that instance. And there it comes a complete new level (nightmare difficulty) of problems which you don't want to deal with :D